# Need help with creating a form for a multi-language structure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I have two tables in my database. The first one is holding category ID's and the second one category names. The reason of holding its values and ids apart is because the website will be multi-language. For example:

```
tableCategory - id | stringID | dateOfCreation
tableString - id | stringID | value | languageID 
// these two tables are connected with their stringIDs, 
// so the categories in the tableCategory can have different names 
// according to the user's language
```

Okay, now, I am using LINQ TO SQL and I want to create a form for an admin to insert new category names. For example:

```
English | Italiano | Français 

entertainment | divertimento | divertissement

// where language names are column names and the values are within a textbox
```

So, how can I accomplish this task by using `Html.TextBox` or `Html.TextBoxFor` helpers? Please provide me a good example with describing also the process in the controller and model. I appreciate your help to a newbie in MVC :)

Comment: This article may help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the blog-link that aligray has posted you, it helped me fixing similar problems :-)